# Create file or registry key without calling NTDLL.DLL

Tags: windows, ntdll

I know that ntdll is always present in the running process but is there a way (not necessarily supported/stable/guaranteed to work) to create a file/key without ever invoking ntdll functions?

Answer (score 1):

NTDLL is at the bottom of the user-mode hierarchy, some of its functions switch to kernel mode to perform their tasks. If you want to duplicate its code then I suppose there is nothing stopping you from decompiling `NtCreateFile` to figure out how it works. Keep in mind that on 32-bit Windows there are 3 different instructions used to enter kernel mode (depending on the CPU type), the exact way and where the transition code lives changes between versions and the system call ids change between versions (and even service packs). You can find a list of system call ids [here](https://j00ru.vexillium.org/2013/11/windows-system-call-and-csr-api-tables-updated/).

I assume you are doing this to avoid people hooking your calls? Detecting your calls? Either way, I can't recommend that you try to do this. Having to test on a huge set of different Windows versions is unmanageable and your software might break on a simple Windows update at any point.

You could create a custom kernel driver that does the work for you but then you are on the hook for getting all the security correct. At least you would have documented functions to call in the kernel.

Comment: *"your software might break on a simple Windows update"* - "Might" is probably the wrong term, it's more like "will". System call IDs on Windows have never been documented, nor are they stable. They have changed in the past and they are literally changing all the time. The "public" interface to the kernel is the Native API.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, registry is stored in `%WINDIR%\System32\config` / `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\config`, excepted your own user's registry which is stored in your own profile, in `%USERPROFILE%\NTUSER.DAT`.

And now, the problems...

1. You don't normally have even a read access to this folder, and this is true even from an elevated process. You'll need to change (and mess up a lot...) the permissions to simply *read* it.
2. Even for your *own* registry, you can't open the binary file - *"Sharing violation"*... So, for system/local machine registries... You can't in fact open ANY registry file for the current machine/session. You would need to shut down your Windows and mount its system drive in another machine/OS to be able to open - and maybe edit - registry files.
3. Real registry isn't a simple file like the `.reg` files. It's a database (you can [look here](https://github.com/msuhanov/regf/blob/master/Windows%20registry%20file%20format%20specification.md) for some elements on its structure). Even when having a full access to the binary files, it won't be fun to add something inside "from scratch", without any sotware support.

So, it's *technically* possible - after all, Windows does it, right? But I doubt that it can be done in a *reasonable* amount of time, and I simply can't see any benefit from doing that since, as you said, `ntdll` is ALWAYS present, loaded and available to be used.

If the purpose is to hack the current machine and/or bypass some lack of privileges, it's a hopeless approach, since you'll need even more privileges to do it - like being able to open your case and extract the system drive or being able to boot on another operating system on the same machine... If it's possible, then there is already tools to access the offline Windows, found on a well-known "Boot CD", so still no need to write in registry without any Windows support.